# FirebaseUI recycleview Isn't working in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebaseui

As i was working with firebasui recycleview in fragment my app is crashing everytime I tried to open it.I have done firebaseui recycleview in normal activity and it didn't crash.I couldn't locate the problem.Any kind of help will be really useful..Thank you

Fragment Class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;

/**
 * Created by Akib on 1/18/2018.
 */

public class BlogActivity extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private Query query;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter;
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_blog, container, false);


        return v;
    }
    public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        View view;
        public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            view=itemView;
        }
        public void setTitle(String title)
        {
            TextView post_title=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            post_title.setText(title);
        }
        public void setDescription(String description)
        {
            TextView post_desc=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
            post_desc.setText(description);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycleview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        query= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<BlogDesc> options=new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<BlogDesc>().setQuery(query,BlogDesc.class).build();
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<BlogDesc, BlogViewHolder>(options) {

            @Override
            public BlogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view;
                view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.blog_row,parent,false);
                return new BlogViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BlogViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull BlogDesc model) {
                holder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                holder.setDescription(model.getDescription());
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
        getActivity().setTitle("Blog");

  }
}
```

MainActivity class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private void displaySelectedScreen(int id)
    {
        Fragment fragment  =null;
        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            fragment=new BlogActivity();
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }
        if(fragment!=null)
        {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.home_content,fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        /*if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {

            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);*/
        displaySelectedScreen(id);
        return true;
    }
}
```

activity_blog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

CardView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/title"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/description"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

activity_home.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Content_home.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/home_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.aust.austpc.austpcportalbeta4.HomeActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home">



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Error:

```
01-19 03:44:05.396 23502-23502/com.aust.austpc.austpcportalbeta4 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.aust.austpc.austpcportalbeta4, PID: 23502
                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aust.austpc.austpcportalbeta4/com.aust.austpc.austpcportalbeta4.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2455)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2515)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5571)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)
                                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:543)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                                       at com.aust.austpc.austpcportalbeta4.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:24)
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6357)
                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2515) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5571) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635) 
                                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:649)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:768)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:839)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                                       at com.aust.austpc.austpcportalbeta4.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:24) 
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6357) 
                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2515) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5571) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635) 
                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:768) 
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708) 
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:839) 
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519) 
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                                       at com.aust.austpc.austpcportalbeta4.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:24) 
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6357) 
                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2515) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5571) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635) 
                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getFont(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/widget/TextView;)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; in class Landroid/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat' appears in /data/app/com.aust.austpc.austpcportalbeta4-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getFont(TintTypedArray.java:119)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:208)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:110)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:81)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708)
                                                                                    at android.
01-19 03:44:35.077 23502-23581/com.aust.austpc.austpcportalbeta4 E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: TIMEOUT
```

Comment: it has something to do with your NavigationView that you are using in the activity_home.xml.. please put a code snippet of your full activity_home design

Comment: done! I have edited the question with the code snippet

Comment: ayout/nav_header_home"
menu/activity_home_drawer"

did you do any change in these two files?

Comment: Still facing the startup crash.

Comment: no i didn't change anything in nav_header_home,xml and activity_home_drawer